# Is it possible get Aws Rds DbInstances by TAG?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

So, I'm using Java API: AWS SDK - 2.17 (v2)

[API_DescribeDBInstances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeDBInstances.html)

There are a couple of default filters, but I want to use my own filter created by TAG.

For example, I can use Filter by Tag for retrieve EC2 instances, but I can't understand how to do that for DbInstances?

This doesn't work

```
    Filter filter = Filter.builder().name("TAG_NAME").values("TAG_VALUE").build();
    DescribeDbInstancesRequest request = DescribeDbInstancesRequest.builder()
            .filters(filter)
            .build();
    DescribeDbInstancesResponse response = amazonRDS.describeDBInstances(request);
```

But pretty same code works for EC2 Instances (API v1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The `DescribeDbInstances()` API call can only filter on IDs, domain and engine.

You would need to do the filtering in your own code.

Comment: Thank you, John, but I think that is pretty strange